# Unable to get Gstreamer1.0 plugins/features

Tags: c, gstreamer, multimedia

I am having trouble working with gstreamer1.0.

```
  gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp3 ! mad ! autoaudiosink

  ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "filesrc".
```

This is what gst-inspect gives

```
  $gst-inspect-1.0 
  staticelements:  bin: Generic bin
  staticelements:  pipeline: Pipeline object

 Total count: 1 plugin, 2 features
```

I tried reinstalling with following command

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0
```

but it dint help..

What am I missing...

Comment: do you have multiple versions of gstreamer? have you been hacking anything before with gstreamer? try to locate gstreamer registry - run `locate registry.dat` - it should be somewhere in directory gstreamer - then delete this file and run gst-inspect-1.0 which shall give you some warnings if anything is wrong.. also try to show blacklisted plugins with `gst-inspect-1.0 -b`

Comment: Also check if you have environment variable GST_PLUGIN_PATH set to something strange.